# Does there exist a self-adjoint operator whose spectrum is just the continuous spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Does there exist a self-adjoint operator whose spectrum is just the continuous spectrum, i.e. no point spectrum and no residue spectrum?

If not, please prove it.

Comment: $(Mf)(x)=xf(x)$ on $L^{2}[0,1]$ has continuous spectrum $[0,1]$ and no other type of spectrum.

Comment: And self-adjoint operators do not have residual spectrum anyway.

Comment: As a note to @DisintegratingByParts comment/answer, you can see that $\sigma(M) = \sigma_c(M) = [0,1]$, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2088197/545914) of his.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to find an example where the Spectrum is equal to the Continuous Spectrum in C\[0,1\]; $\sigma_c(A)=\sigma(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237929/i-want-to-find-an-example-where-the-spectrum-is-equal-to-the-continuous-spectrum)